# Return value for which a function reaches its smallest negative value in python

Tags: python

It's pretty late, so I don't know how clear this will be.

I have a function f(x), I want to get the value of x from a list for which f(x) reachest the *smallest* negative value, namely:

```
x = [0, 2, 4, 6]
f(x) = [200, 0, -3, -1000]
```

In this case, I would like something to return the value 4 in x, which gave me -3. I don't want the absolute minimum (-1000), but the negative value with the lowest absolute value.

I hope that makes sense, thanks a lot for your help.

**UPDATE**

I was trying to simplify the problem, maybe too much. Here's the thing: I have a list of 2D points that form a polygon and I want to order them clockwise.

For that, I take the cross product between each point and the rest and select the next point based on getting the negative cross product (which tells me the sense of rotation) from the previous and which has the smallest absolute value (which tells me it really is the next point).

so, say:

```
x = [(1,1), (-1,-1), (-1,1), (1,-1)]
```

and I would like to get

```
x = [(1,1), (1,-1), (-1,-1), (-1,1)]
```

I'm doing

```
for point in x:
   cp = [numpy.cross(point, p) for p in x]
   # and then some magic to select the right point...
```

Thanks for your help again.

Comment: What did you try, where are you stuck?

Comment: That is called the **largest negative** number.

Comment: How about if f(x) contains duplicate numbers satisfying the criteria?

Answer (score 2):

```
a = [0, 2, 4, 6]
b = [200, 0, -3, -1000]

value = max([x for x in b if x < 0])
print a[b.index(value)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
inputs = [0, 2, 4, 6]
outputs = [200, 0, -3, -1000]
max = min(outputs)
for n in outputs:
    if n >= 0:
        continue
    if n > max:
        max = n
print inputs[outputs.index(max)]
```

Answer (score 0):

The following solution should work well in most cases

```
    [ z for z in x if f(z) == max( f(y) for y in x if f(y) < 0 ) ]
```

One characteristic of this solution is that if there is a repetition, i.e. several `x`'s producing the same biggest negative, all of them will be returned.

Answer (score 0):

```
x = [0, 2, 4, 6]
fx = [200, 0, -3, -1000]

print(x[fx.index(max(n for n in fx if n < 0))])
```